# Custom font OpenSans in visual studio not displaying XAML, UWP

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am trying to get a "custom" font working in a UWP XAML C# project [Open Sans Extrabold Italic](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans)
I have added it to my project and it shows up correctly in Properties but when I select it, it doesn't work. *(All the default fonts work.)*

I have also tried changing the XAML to `FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf#OpenSans"`

What am I doing incorrectly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FontName you used is not correct, it should be "**Open Sans**", so please change it as

```
FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf#Open Sans"
```

Comment: It's strange I was pretty sure I had already tried this, I should note that I had to press Local Machine before it updated to show correctly in the designer, so that's probably why it didn't look like it was working when I tried different font names before.